# Function to check for a match of words

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a custom function.

Columns A & B both contain text.

In C2 when I write the function it will check for a match of words even in different order or if a partial match from all rows of column A and if found it will write the value of B2 in C2, else write "Match Not Found".

The function is not returning the correct value.

```
Function slookup(stext As String)
    Dim chtext() As String
    Dim stext1() As String

    Dim lastrow, wrdcount, wrdcount1, c, j, k As Long

    lastrow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    MsgBox lastrow
    For c = 2 To lastrow
        k = 0
        chtext() = Split(stext, " ")
        wrdcount = UBound(chtext()) + 1

        stext1 = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & c).Value)
        wrdcount1 = UBound(stext1) + 1
        If wrdcount = wrdcount1 Then

            For n = 0 To wrdcount - 1
                For j = 0 To wrdcount - 1
                    If StrComp(chtext(n), stext1(j), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                        k = k + 1
                    End If
                Next
            Next

            If k = wrdcount Then
                ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = stext
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If k <> wrdcount Then
        ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = "No Match Found"
    End If

End Function
```

[image: Excel Sheet]

Comment: Can you provide a sheet with expected results? It's not entirely clear to me what your comparison requirements are. Also, this line: `Dim lastrow, wrdcount, wrdcount1, c, j, k As Long`, `k` is the only variable that is being declared as `Long`. All others variables are being declared as `Variant`. In VBA, each variable has to be declared individually

Comment: C2-"No Match" , C3 -Parotta, C4 -Paneer Butter Masala, C5 - Poha, c6 - Chilly. And I have done hundreds of VBA program where I have declared the multiple variables at a time. I got no issue with that.

Comment: If i understand your comparison, shouldn't `C5` be **`Pohas`** and not **`Poha`**?

Comment: Suggestion about your variable declarations was to help. If that's upsetting for you, I'll leave it that. Hope someone helps you, good luck

Comment: Interesting, how should the code, which compares A4-"Chilly" with B4-"Butter Paneer Masala" gets the result of C4-"Paneer Butter Masala" and compares A6-"Aloo Jeera" with B6-"Chilly" and gets the C6-"Chilly" as result,  look like.

Comment: I am not upsetting, I always here for suggestion. I have tried that too. I also figure out the program is working fine. Yes first I am looking for exact match then I will try with partial match and the match will be Chilly and Paneer Butter Masala for now. Just something there if K=wrdcount. It enters the loop,I have checked it but not writing the results.

Comment: It's not about comparing A2 with B2. It's like comparing B2 with all the rows of column A.

Comment: It's not able to execute this line even I select a different cell or a fixed text. ActiveSheet.Range("C2").Value = stext

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found the issue, it's more of a glitch. I am doing everything but instead of returning the value I just want to write the value manually. Find the answer and also corrected program now I will try the partial match with it. This one is like fuzzy lookup.

```
Function slookup(stext As String)
'Application.Volatile (True)
    Dim chtext() As String
    Dim stext1() As String
    Dim stext2 As String
    stext2 = stext
    Dim lastrow, wrdcount, wrdcount1, c, j, k As Integer

    lastrow = Sheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    For c = 2 To lastrow
        k = 0
        chtext() = Split(stext, " ")
        wrdcount = UBound(chtext()) + 1
'        MsgBox wrdcount

        stext1 = Split(Sheets(1).Range("A" & c).Value)
        wrdcount1 = UBound(stext1()) + 1
            If wrdcount = wrdcount1 Then

                For n = 0 To wrdcount - 1
                    For j = 0 To wrdcount1 - 1
'                        MsgBox chtext(n) & " - " & stext1(j)
                        If StrComp(chtext(n), stext1(j), vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
                            k = k + 1
'                            Debug.Print k
                        End If
                    Next
                Next
'                MsgBox k & " - " & wrdcount
                If k = wrdcount Then
                    slookup = stext2
                    Exit Function
                End If
            End If
    Next

If k <> wrdcount Then
    slookup = "No Match Found"
End If


End Function
```